# Google Sheets Ap-script Indexof

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use IndexOf and it keeps returning -1 (no match) when the value is in the array.  I am new to this so I am not sure why it won't work.  my end goal is to return the row number of the first instance of the matching data.

```
var lookup_array = sales_sheet.getRange(1,1,3,1).getValues();
var index = lookup_array.indexOf(newsheet_name);
```

lookup_array = [[account_manager], [john doe], [john doe]]

newsheet_name = john doe

index = -1

I would expect value to = 1 since john doe is the 2nd value in the array.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. So in order to use `indexOf()`, please modify as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

In this modification, 2 dimensional array is converted to 1 dimensional array by `map()`, and `indexOf()` is used.

#### Modified script:

```
var newsheet_name = "john doe";
var lookup_array = sales_sheet.getRange(1,1,3,1).getValues(); // [["account_manager"], ["john doe"], ["john doe"]]
var res = lookup_array.map(function(e) {return e[0]}).indexOf(newsheet_name);
Logger.log(res) // 1
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)